# How to Count number of days?

Tags: sql-server

Using SQL Server 2005

Table1

```
ID FromDate ToDate

001 23-02-2009 25-02-2009
001 27-02-2009 29-02-2009
002 12-02-2009, 25-03-2009
```

...,

Table2

```
ID Name Total

001 Raja 30
002 Ravi 22
```

I want to get total day for the personid

Tried Query,

```
SELECT
   table2.Id, table2.name, table2.total, 
   datediff(day, table1.fromdate, table2.todate) 
FROM table1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.personid = table2.personid
```

Getting output

```
ID Name Total Days

001 Raja 30 3
001 Raja 30 3
...,
```

It should total the days and it should display in one line,

Note: Suppose I am selecting the particular period date means it should display that days only

For example

where date between 26-02-2009 to 03-03-2009, It should display

```
ID Name Total Days

001 Raja 30 3
...,
```

Because am taking date after 25-02-2009,

```
Expected Output

ID Name Total Days

001 Raja 30 6
002 Ravi 22 16
```

How to modify my query?

Comment: By the way, in the data dump you've included for table1, 29-02-2009 isn't a valid date. 2009 wasn't a leap year and SQL Server will shout loudly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DATEDIFF gives the number of days difference between two dates, so in the same way the different between 1 and 3 is 2 (3 - 1 = 2), DATEDIFF(d) is effectively D2 - D1. So to compensate for the extra day you want to count, you need to DATEADD a day to either (ToDate or FromDate) to offset your dates:

```
SELECT table2.id, table2.Name, table2.Total, SUM(DATEDIFF(d, DATEADD(d, -1, table1.FromDate), table1.ToDate))
    FROM table1
        INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
    GROUP BY table2.id, table2.Name, table2.Total
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  table2.Id, table2.name, table2.total,
        COALESCE(
        (
        SELECT  SUM(DATEDIFF(day, table1.fromdate, table1.todate) + 1)
        FROM    table1
        WHERE   table1.personid = table2.personid
        ), 0) AS [days]
FROM    table2
```

Comment: No, Am using DATEDIFF(day, table1.fromdate, table1.todate), so suppose fromdate = 24-02-2009 and todate = 28-02-2009 means It should give total as 5 day, But now it is giving 3 days only. It is avoiding 24 and 28. How to get that count also.

Comment: See the post update. If your dates are `24-02-2009` and `28-02-2009`, the `DATEDIFF` will give you `4` days, not `3`.

Answer (score 0):

I think a GROUP BY query would be simpler:

```
SELECT table2.Id, table2.name, table2.total, 
SUM(DATEDIFF(day, table1.fromdate, table1.todate)) AS Days
FROM table1 
left outer join table2 on 
table1.personid = table2.personid
GROUP BY table2.Id, table2.name, table2.total
```

Comment: No, Am using DATEDIFF(day, table1.fromdate, table1.todate), so suppose fromdate = 24-02-2009 and todate = 28-02-2009 means It should give total as 5 day, But now it is giving 3 days only. It is avoiding 24 and 28. How to get that count also.